# 'glfwCreateWindow' freezes when called in Dllmain

Tags: c++, dll, glfw, dllmain

When I call `glfwCreateWindow` in `DllMain`, the program freezes and CPU usage drops to 0%.

My code works fine if I change the type of program from `.dll` to `.exe`, and replace `DllMain` with `main`.

Here is part of my code:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwReason,
    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "glfw init failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "window creation failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    return TRUE;
}
```

When I run the program, 1 gets printed, however the program freezes and 2 never gets printed.

Comment: The comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852156/how-to-use-dllmain-to-run-background-code) answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **very** limited number of things you can do in `DllMain`, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

You're going to have to find some way to defer the calls to GLFW.  Perhaps an explicit initialisation call on your DLL is the way to go.

Comment: How could this be done?

Comment: It can't, really.  Why do you want to?

Comment: I certainly know this can be done, I just do not know how. I am trying to use `dllmain` to run background code.